# Which enhanced instruction set does an application use?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

Is there any **reliable and easy** way to establish whether an exe or dll uses a particular enhanced instruction set (e.g. SSE4.1)?

Disassembling it with `ndiasm` seems to produce a listing which you could test for the presence of the specific instructions, but it is not so since the "rubbish" is decompiled (any hex data is interpreted as instructions) producing false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to do this by running the program and observing which actual instructions get sent to the CPU. You could do this, for example, in a VMware virtual machine, which lets you debug at the CPU instruction level from the host. There's even a Visual Studio plugin for this purpose. A regular old debugger would *work* if you have the patience to single-step through the code at the instruction level; however, a debugger won't let you break on a specific opcode or opcode range.

Programs are able to emit native instructions to be executed at runtime, which are not included in the code sections of the executable. If it weren't for this behavior, interpreted languages like Java, .NET and JavaScript would be horribly slow. By allowing code to be written at runtime, high-level scripting languages can be compiled into native code and stored in RAM dynamically while adjusting the code to run fastest per the actual application use cases (for example, if a certain branch is never ever taken, eliminate that branch from the native code). This is called JIT compilation.

Even some native programs do something *similar* to JIT compilation, in that, the raw code in the binary on disk may be compatible all the way down to a 486, but the program will dynamically determine which processor it's running on, and either generate code to run on that processor, or use some code that's in the "data" section of the binary as executable code.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032055/420156) is why a traditional debugger like `gdb` will not allow you to break on a specific opcode or assembly instruction. A semi-performant solution to this problem will probably involve some type of virtual machine, since the hypervisor can see exactly what code the hypervised guest is running, and provide that as output to a program or a user interface on the host.